# ambari hadoop cluster + what are the differences between ambari 2.5.0 to the new version - 2.6.0

Tags: linux, hadoop, bigdata, hadoop2, ambari

dear colleges and friends

until now we installed from scratch the ambari clusters based on the following versions:

```
HDP-2.6.0.3
ambari - 2.5.0

here are the new pkgs :

HDP-2.6.3.0-centos7-rpm.tar.gz
ambari-2.6.0.0-centos7.tar.gz
```

we created scripts installation for **HDP-2.6.0 & ambari-2.5.0** include blueprint installation scripts , and our scripts are very stable

but now we want to go next and to installed from scratch the following new versions kits:

```
HDP - 2.6.3 
ambari 2.6.x
```

**so my question is:**

based on our current scripts

do we need to change something in our scripts that works fine on **HDP-2.6.0.3-8 & ambari - 2.5.0** , in order to fit the new version - **2.6.3 and ambari 2.6.x** ?

or maybe new kits & configuration - should be installed & configured exactly the same ?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell. Do you have separate environments (at least two: dev and prod). You could try to upgrade the dev environment and see how the new version works out.